# Resolver conflito de Toogles bootstrap e Checkbox

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema que não consegui resolver, tenho um `toggle` feito em `bootstrap`que está em conflito com um `checkbox` em minha página, tenho um `checkbox` que ao ao clicar para marca/desmarca o `toggle` é acionado.

O código do meu checkbox é esse:

```
<input id="MarcaDesmarca" type="checkbox" name="MarcaDesmarca" />
```

```
$(function () {
    $('#MarcaDesmarca').click(function () {
        var val = this.checked;
        $("input[name='Lista[]']").each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', val);
        });
    });
});
```

A imagem do que tenho é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A estrutura está assim:

```
<div class="toggle toggle-transparent toggle-bordered-full margin-top-20">
         <div class="row">           
            <div class="col-sm-5">Descrição</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">Nome</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Data</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"><input id="MarcaDesmarca" type="checkbox" name="MarcaDesmarca" /></div>                
        </div> 

<!-- CABEÇALHO DO TOGGLE !-->
    <?php foreach ($Resultado as $Retorno) {  

        $IdUnicoop = $Retorno->IdUnicoop; 

        // UNIDADE
        $sqlUnicoop = "SELECT * 
                         FROM `cadUnicoop` 
                        WHERE `IdUnicoop` = ?
                          AND `Ativo` = 1                                             
                        ORDER BY Nome ASC";
        $arrayUnicoop  = array($IdUnicoop);
        $ResUnicoop = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sqlUnicoop, $arrayUnicoop, TRUE);

        // NOME DA UNIDADE
        foreach ($ResUnicoop as $NomeUnicoop) { 
            $NomeUnicoop->Nome;
        }                   

    ?>       
<div class="toggle">
    <label>
         <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-sm-5"><?php echo $Retorno->Descricao; ?></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo $NomeUnicoop->Nome; ?></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"><?php echo implode("/", array_reverse(explode("-", $Retorno->Data))); ?></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Lista[]" value="<?php echo $Retorno->IdOrdem; ?>" /></div>
        </div>  

    </label>
    <!-- CONTEÚDO DO TOGGLE !-->
    <div class="toggle-content">
         <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-sm-3"><?php echo $Retorno->Produto; ?></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><?php echo $Retorno->Safra; ?></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><?php echo $Retorno->Peso; ?></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><?php echo $Retorno->Valor; ?></div>
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Função `Toggle`

```
    function _toggle() {

    var $_t = this,
        previewParClosedHeight = 25;

    jQuery("div.toggle.active > p").addClass("preview-active");
    jQuery("div.toggle.active > div.toggle-content").slideDown(400);
    jQuery("div.toggle > label").click(function(e) {

        var parentSection   = jQuery(this).parent(),
            parentWrapper   = jQuery(this).parents("div.toggle"),
            previewPar      = false,
            isAccordion     = parentWrapper.hasClass("toggle-accordion");

        if(isAccordion && typeof(e.originalEvent) != "undefined") {
            parentWrapper.find("div.toggle.active > label").trigger("click");
        }

        parentSection.toggleClass("active");

        if(parentSection.find("> p").get(0)) {

            previewPar                  = parentSection.find("> p");
            var previewParCurrentHeight = previewPar.css("height");
            var previewParAnimateHeight = previewPar.css("height");
            previewPar.css("height", "auto");
            previewPar.css("height", previewParCurrentHeight);

        }

        var toggleContent = parentSection.find("> div.toggle-content");

        if(parentSection.hasClass("active")) {

            jQuery(previewPar).animate({height: previewParAnimateHeight}, 350, function() {jQuery(this).addClass("preview-active");});
            toggleContent.slideDown(350);

        } else {

            jQuery(previewPar).animate({height: previewParClosedHeight}, 350, function() {jQuery(this).removeClass("preview-active");});
            toggleContent.slideUp(350);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Não consegue colocar a parte relevante aqui nas snippets? O que acontece de mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é um conflito, o que está ocorrendo é que no seu código, o toggle está configurado para ativar quando ele clicar em toda a área do cabecalho, inclusive os checkboxes que fazem parte dele, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ideal seria você definir um local onde o toggle deverá ser ativado, ou no nome do usuário, ou na seta, como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim após que estruturar de maneira correta, seu problema será solucionado.

Comment: Olá @Thales Chemenian, grande ajuda, obrigado.